# how to insert '*' before 'S' and '*' after 'S' in StringBuffer java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuffer

How to insert `*` before `S` and `*` after `S`
StringBuffer Java?

```
StringBuffer textInFile= new StringBuffer ("Stanford ");
public void convertToPTD(PlainTextDocument ptd)
    {

            if(ptd.textInFile.charAt(i)=='S')
{
        ptd.textInFile.......???
        }
            System.out.println(ptd.textInFile);

        return;

    }
```

Comment: So you want to replace all instances of `S` with `*S*`?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced more than ten years ago by StringBuilder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "replaced"? Another verb might be more to the point.

Comment: @La-comadreja Certainly not - that would show in the javadoc.

Comment: @La-comadreja Not \@Deprecated but the Javadoc says "As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."

Comment: I suspect you should be using plain String rather StringBuilder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey although making the replacement in a String is simpler (replaceAll()), the StringBuffer class also supports methods that would do the task.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.replace` method. An example:

```
char c = '*';
String s = "S";
String str = "Stanford";
String rep = str.replace(s, c + s + c);
```

Comment: this question is about a StringBuffer not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to find the list of indices where "S" is.

Your second step is, for each index, replace "S" with "*S*".

Here is how:

```
int i = -1;
while (true) {
    i = buffer.indexOf(i + 1, "S");
    if (i == -1) break; // No more occurrences of "S" are found
    buffer = buffer.replace(i, i + 1, "*S*");
}
```

indexOf() returns -1 if there are no occurrences of the substring we want in the section of the String we're looking at.

Comment: Does this run any risk of referring to the wrong indices after a replacement?

Comment: no, because we're looking through each of the old indices at their new positions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it recursively to suit your needs.

Below is a piece of code I have tested on my machine. Hope it works for you:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("WhereStanford");
str = str.replace(str.indexOf("S", 0), str.indexOf("S", 0)+1, "*S*");
```